# Ansible - Iterate Thru Folders Containing Files. Output to file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Hoping someone might be able to provide me an answer with this. I currently have a folder structure like so.

```
/BASE_DIR
    /FOLDER_A
       - file1.txt
       - file2.txt
    /FOLDER_B
    /FOLDER_C
       - file3.txt
```

Im trying to create a playbook that could tell me which folders contain files. My end goal is to have a flat file with:

```
FOLDER_A, file1.txt
FOLDER_A, file2.txt
FOLDER_C, file3.txt
```

This is my playbook currently:

```
- name: get files from all folders
  shell: cd /BASE_DIR/{{ item.name }} && ls -p | grep -v / |grep .txt |cat
  with_items:
     - name: "FOLDER_A"
     - name: "FOLDER_B"
     - name: "FOLDER_C"
  register: "fileitems"

- name: combine to have folder name as key, filenames as values
  set_fact:
     folders_with_files: "{{ folders_with_files|default({}) | combine( { item.item.name: item.stdout_lines } ) }}"
  with_items: "{{ fileitems.results }}"
  when: "{{ item.stdout_lines|length }} > 0"

- debug:
  var: folders_with_files
```

I thought I could iterate through each folder looking for *.txt and then use a combine, it would be an easy way to iterate.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "folders_with_files": {
        "FOLDER_A": [
            "file1.txt",
            "file2.txt"
        ],
        "FOLDER_C": [
            "file3.txt"
        ]
    }
}
```

But even with this output,  I don't think I can properly parse it the way I need to. I thought maybe a nested loop could help, but that would mean I would need to know the name of the keys beforehand.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
T

Comment: Are you sure you have chosen the right tool for your task?

Comment: @techraf - Yes. I know this could be easily solved in a shell script. But this is part of a larger playbook and I was hoping to see if Ansible can solve this on its own.. From my answer it can, just not as easy as other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go figure as soon as I post the question, I find my own answer...

I decided to remove the combine and just append to an empty list.

```
- set_fact:
 folders_with_files: []

- name: get all sql from each adapter
  shell: cd /tmp/{{ item.name }} && ls -p | grep -v / |grep .txt |cat
  with_items:
    - name: "FOLDER_A"
    - name: "FOLDER_B"
    - name: "FOLDER_C"
  register: "fileitems"

- name: combine to display which adapters have files
  set_fact:
    folders_with_files: "{{ folders_with_files + [{ 'name': item.item.name, 'files': item.stdout_lines }] }}"
  with_items: "{{ fileitems.results }}"
  when: "{{ item.stdout_lines|length }} > 0"

- debug:
    var: folders_with_files
```

My output then became:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "folders_with_files": [
        {
            "files": [
                "file1.txt",
                "file2.txt"
            ],
            "name": "FOLDER_A"
        },
        {
            "files": [
                "file3.txt"
            ],
            "name": "FOLDER_C"
        }
    ]
}
```

I could then use a with_subelements:

```
- name: echo
  shell: echo "{{ item.0.name }}, {{ item.1}}" >> /tmp/output.txt
  with_subelements:
     - "{{ folders_with_files }}"
     - files
```